# Accessing a SQL Server 2008 Express Database Using TCP/IP

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, tcp, user-instance

VS 2010 comes with SQL 2008 Express, and upgrades existing project's databases to SQL 2008 as well (please correct me if im wrong!) - however, I now have a problem - I need to simulate a hosting situation on my PC, where a desktop application connects using TCP/IP to the SQL 2008 database.

**Problems**
1. The database as created in VS 2010 is a user instance which I cant seem to access via TCP/IP - I assume I need to make this a server instance to do so?
2. I have SQL Management Studio Express 2005 which wont allow me to connect to SQL 2008 to attach the user instance and have torn my hair out trying to install Studio Express 2008, but still failed

Can anyone tell me if Im either on the right track or if there's a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly enable TCP/IP on SQL Express.

[http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/](https://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/)
https://web.archive.org/web/20151204091559/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx